# sharepoint jquery autocomplete clear textbox if no value

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, autocomplete

i created textbox which works on autocomplete function based on data from another list. I need to clear the textbox if the user has not selected any item or he has entered wrong text. below is my code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://address/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: function (xmlResponse) {
            var domElementArray = $("z\\:row", xmlResponse);
            var dataMap = domElementArray.map(function () {
                return {
                    value: $(this).attr('ows_AirportCode'),
                    id: $(this).attr('ows_AirportCode')
                };
            });
            var data = dataMap.get();

            //Find the Sharepoint Portal Search Box (this is a poor selector, but it is not properly named by sharepoint, well it is but INamingContainer getrs in the way)   
            $("input[title='AirportCode Required Field']").autocomplete(
        {
            source: data,

            miniLength: 3,
            response: function (event, ui) {
                // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
                if (ui.content.length == 0) {
                    $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
                } else {
                    $("#empty-message").empty();
                }
            }
        }
        );
        }
    }); //.ajax
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the change event on autocomplete and compare the selected value against your array of list values for a match:

```
.autocomplete({
   ...
   .change: function( event, ui ) {
      var input = $("input[title='AirportCode Required Field']");
      var selectedValue = input.val();
      var valid = false;
      $.each(data , function (i, item) {
         if (item.value === selectedValue) valid = true;
      });

      if (valid == false){
        // clear the input if not found
        input.val('');
      }
   }
})
```